# Updating firebase library to 16.0.0 raises google play services dependency issue

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, google-play-services

My project was working fine until one day, because of no reason (I didn't change anything), gradle started giving this strange error:

```
Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzabo
```

At the time of this error my project level gradle was like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
            // Alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
        }
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.3'
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.8.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.bintray.com/sayyam/maven'
        }
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and this was my app level gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        deviceCheck
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 8
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    .....other dependencies.....
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I searched and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50149536/3602767) answer on stackoverflow. Which says that this issue might be related to firebase dependency version and google-services plugin. So i updated `google-services` plugin version to `4.0.0` and firebase to its latest version `16.0.0`. And as one could expect from gradle, it gave another error which seems to be related to firebase version 16.0.0.

Whenever i change firebase version to 16.0.0, apparently it tries to automatically upgrade google play services dependencies to 16.0.0 too. Which doesn't EVEN exist! It raises following gradle error:

```
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0 
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0   
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0  
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.0 
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.0 
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.0 
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.0    
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:16.0.0
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:16.0.0
```

I have tried to force version of gms libraries using resolutionStrategy but to no avail. What should i do? What am I doing wrong?

NOTE: I didn't change play services libraries version explicitly, gradle seems to do it because of firebase.

**EDIT:** This problem can be solved by the solution given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50512955/highest-firebase-version-code-is-used-for-compiling-play-services-library-too) question, but still its not duplicate because in my case onesignal plugin was updating only **gms** libraries version and not **firebase** version. So anybody facing this problem won't search for keywords used in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50512955/highest-firebase-version-code-is-used-for-compiling-play-services-library-too) question.

Comment: which firebase depedencies did u upgrade to 16.0.0?

Comment: firebase-core and firebase-invites..I have only these two in gradle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highest firebase version code is used for compiling play services library too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50512955/highest-firebase-version-code-is-used-for-compiling-play-services-library-too)

Comment: Yea it is, i didn't come across it because i wasn't even expecting it was related to onesignal as it was working fine and issue was appearing after updating firebase

Comment: Also note that in my case the onesignal plugin was updating **gms** libraries version not **firebase** . So anybody facing this issue won't search for keywords used in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50512955/highest-firebase-version-code-is-used-for-compiling-play-services-library-too) question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have run into the same issues as the poster of https://stackoverflow.com/a/50516114/7070704 with the same resolution.

Basically, the com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin plugin is forcing an uplift on your dependencies onto something which does not exist.

Comment: Dude thanks alot! I wasn't even expecting that this issue might be related to that stupid plugin as it was working fine before. The issue resolved by updating the onesignal plugin version to 0.10.1... I also updated onesignal dependency to 3.9.1

Comment: also excluded firebase-messaging from onesignal as it was old and creating conflicts related to firebase-iid which is also included in firebase-invites. Added firebase-messaging separately with version 17.0.0